# postgresql function returning every row containing one of the word from a string

Tags: postgresql, function

I have create the following function in pgAdmin 4 for returning as Json the ebooks having a word in their column 'synopsis':

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION searchA (searchEntry varchar(255)) RETURNS json LANGUAGE plpgsql  
AS 
$$ 
    BEGIN
        RETURN jsonb_agg(row_to_json(a)) FROM (SELECT * FROM ebook WHERE to_tsvector(synopsis) @@ to_tsquery(searchEntry)) a;       
    END;   
$$
```

but I would like for this function to be able return every ebook who contains at least one of the word from a string character.
How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, then
If searchEntry = 'so very best application'
You want to view all records which has any of these words.

You can do it using this syntaxis:

```
WHERE to_tsvector(synopsis) @@ to_tsquery('so | very | best | application'); -- this is OR logic operation. 

WHERE to_tsvector(synopsis) @@ to_tsquery('so & very & best & application'); -- this is AND logic operation.
```

And you can converting your searchEntry string to above format using replace function, for example

```
searchEntry = replace(searchEntry, ' ', ' | ');
```